# "Dynamic" Pricing System

Tags: interpreter, configurable-product

Soon I'll be working on a project that amounts to what is essentially an e-commerce app for configured products. This question is about ways to implement pricing schemes that can change from day to day, so we want to get the pricing logic out of code and into a database, but not in a way that causes the database to do all the work.

The basic idea is this, there are 5 attributes. You pick an option from each of those attributes. Then you start adding products to your cart. All the product you add will have those 5 attributes tacked onto them (the attributes will affect the pricing). Once you've added a product, you can apply modifications to it (the attributes will also be applied to the modifications).

So, what we've got at this point is a product (which has a fixed base price) with some information about it (that will modify the price), and zero or more modifications (which has a fixed price) and some information about them (which will modify the price). Modifications can also incur additional charges. For instance, if company A uses this software and they price their items using: BASE_PRICE + $50 * NUM_WHIRLIGIGS and the item has a modification that adds a WHIRLIGIG, that will have to be reflected in the price.

Do you know of any examples of different pricing systems that I might find useful when determining how to set this up? Do you have better ideas?

My current best thought is below, you can skip it if you're not curious about the particulars of the method and just want to get right to the answering!

For any given item (or collection of items) the company could use a special interface to set up pricing formulas which would then be interpreted and evaluated at run-time.

So for PRODUCT_A, the company might put in something like BASE_PRICE + WHIRLIGIG_UPCHARGE * NUM_WHIRLIGIGS. And the software, when it comes time to price it, would look at how many WHIRLIGIGS the item has, as well as how many WHIRLIGIGS are added by any modifications.

Does anyone have experience implementing this kind of interpreter? How did it turn out? Was it difficult/troublesome?

Thanks in advance for all the awesome input I'll sure I'll get. :P

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this is usually handled with product bundles which have components.  So a product with 5 additional subcomponents would not be base + 5 * addon, but SUM(base, addon, addon, addon, addon, addon).

So your product table may either be self-referential or there is some kind of link table which says which sub-products are allowed to be attached to which products.

In my experience, pricing is usually stored on a product/customer or contract basis, so that's another table.

Then the actual orders themselves contain product bundles.  If the order is a quote, then the pricing is frozen (up to the expiration of the quote).

When an quote or order is turned into an invoice, at that time the pricing is either locked in from the main pricing or the quote, depending upon the pricing timing paradigm.

Comment: It might help to note that the configured product is kitchen cabinetry. And, unfortunately, any given manufacturer will price their product in a different way than the last. Some of them do in fact do things like: PRICE = CABINET_BASE_PRICE * FINISH_UPCHARGE + (BASE_COST_OF_DOOR * FINISH_UPCHARGE * NUM_DOORS)

Comment: And if the cabinet has modifications applied to it you can add a third term that's something like "+ BASE_MOD_COST * FINISH_UPCHARGE". The real issue is that there's so many ways they can do it (and most of them don't even make sense to the manufacturer--they can't price cabinets without the aid of specialized software in some cases), and I have to be flexible enough to allow any sort of formula they might come up with.

Comment: @Anthony Compton I'm not sure.  Are some things attributes of the order? - like all the separate cabinets are going to have the same finish upcharge, but do they have to remember to apply it to each one?  You can certainly interpret formulas in many languages on the fly in your application.  Seems like you are going to have to have some kind of scope, you'll probably not be able to handle just any kind of formula they can come up with.